# What is the passphrase-file in apache2?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl

I'm referring to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/71043/ssl-password-on-apache2-restart?s=275b3be7-5cca-45ea-82c9-99f99cbb6901) question. What is the 'passphrase-file' mentioned in here? Please clarify.

Comment: Why don't you comment on that question and on its answers ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is quite clear on the topic. The passphrase-file is a simple text file that contains the 2 lines

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "passphrase"
```

You may have to make it executable, but I'm not sure.

Max Alginin's answer to the original question is also doable and (a bit) less effort, I'd say.

Comment: where can I find this file? Or should I create a file with this content and save? then what will be the  file name for it?